# Multithreading MMO Server. A thread per area OK?

Tags: c#, multiplayer, mmo, multithreading

As a personal project, I'm setting up a MMO, and writing the server in C#/.NET Core.

As of now my architecture is as follows: The world exists of different areas ( you can go from area to area trough portals ). An area is called a 'room' on my server. Each room has it's own list of clients ( players, each with their TCP stream ).

Now I was wondering if it was ok that I run each room on it's own thread. Each room will manage it's own update cycle ( game loop / room ), as it's independant of other rooms.

My worry is that as the game grows, I will get lots of areas and that a thread per area isn't that great of an idea.

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong or non-benificial in the future ? Am I better off having 1 thread for the game logic for all the rooms ? Or is it ok to have a thread per room ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379272/multithreading-thread-per-area-for-an-mmo-server-good-idea). Cross posting is not allowed on stack exchange sites. Please choose the site you think will give you the best answer for your situation and post only there.

Answer (score 7):

I think this might be a viable architecture. The biggest source of bugs in multithreaded applications is shared access to data. So when the rooms have little to no communication with each other and need little to no access to the data not explicitly owned by them, then they seem like the obvious candidate for units of parallelization.

If you are worried about *too much* parallelization, keep in mind that it is usually easier to reduce threading than to introduce more of it. When it turns out you would like to handle rooms sequentially after all, then it is usually not much of a refactoring effort to change your update-method to process multiple rooms in a loop instead of just one. On the other hand, chopping a single-threaded architecture into a multi-threaded one after the fact can quickly end up in a buggy mess.

By the way, you might want to organize your code around the [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and pass `Task`s to it where each task consists of performing a single update-tick for a single room. The ThreadPool [can be configured](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_ThreadPool_SetMaxThreads_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to use a specific number of threads. You shouldn't set it higher than the number of (virtual) CPU cores. When you give it more tasks than it has threads, those tasks will be enqueued and processed as soon as a thread is finished. That means you can leave your update scheduling to the framework.